# Is there a way to throw all Selenium exceptions in Python as a single parent exception type?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, logging, kibana

I am working on a suite of Selenium scrapers and monitoring the results of scraper runs all in one place. It would be helpful to be able to take a quick look at the logs and see if a scraper error is one that I expected and raised vs. an unexpected error thrown by Selenium. Selenium can throw a variety of different errors at runtime though, for example NoSuchElementException, InvalidElementStateException, etc.

I know these exceptions can be imported and purposefully raised from selenium.common.exceptions. Is there a way to roll that entire exception class into a single class for the purpose of my logging? Can I somehow define a parent class SeleniumException and have all of the Selenium exceptions map to this one? That way in my logs it would read that a SeleniumException occurred.

If anyone has ideas I'd appreciate it. I'm working in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

They already all inherit from `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException()` so you can capture them using that class. From there you can than create some log for them. For example like this:

```py
try:
    # code that can throw selenium exceptn
except selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException as e:
    logging.exception('a WebDriverException happened')
```